# Showing A is not invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 4 & 6 \\
0 & 3 & 8 & 5 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 7 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 9 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

We are asked to show A is not invertible through elimination.

Here is what I tried :

Proof by columns :

$$
\text{let}~~ A^{-1}A=1\\
\text{then}~~ A^{-1}x_3=e_3\\
$$

where
$$
x_{3} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\
8 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is the $3^{rd}$ column of $A$ and

$$
e_3
$$
is the $3^{rd}$ column of $I$ which is

$$
e_3=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This means that

$$
A^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\
8 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Let $3^{rd}$ row of $A^{-1}$ be :

$$
A^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
x&
y&
z&
t&
\end{bmatrix}
$$

We end up with the following equations:
$$
2x=0\\
x+3y=0\\
4x+8y=1\\
6x+5y+7z+9t=0\\
$$
$$
x=y=0
$$

But here we can't satisfy. so this isn't invertable
Here we can see that once we multiply, we can't get $1$ in the $3^{rd}$ element of $e_3$

However my teacher didn't accept this proof. Instead she asked for a proof by rows, and said that the language I use in this proof isn't mathematical? Can you guys make this a little bit mathematical,  and how do I proof by rows?

Every help is appreciated :)

Comment: Your proof, if not wrong, is incomplete. It is possible that $(x,y,z,t)x_3=1$. E.g. $(\frac14,0,0,0)x_3=1$.

Comment: It depends what you mean by elimination. Usually this refers to  set of equations, but can mean perform elementary row operations on matrics. If we interpret it as elementary row operations, then letting $r_{k}$ denote row $k$ of the matrix, we see that $r_{4} \to r_{4} - \frac{9}{7}r_{3}$ is an elementary row operation which results in a matrix with a row of zeros, which is certainly not invertible: since elementary row operations do not affect invertibility, the original matrix is not invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a linear dependence between rows $r_3$ and $r_4$, we have $r_3=\frac79r_4$. This is sufficient to deduce that the matrix is not invertible.

You could also calculate the determinant (this is easy because the matrix is triangle, it's the product of the diagonal coefficients), which is $0$. Hence the matrix is not invertible.

---

There are many ways of showing this... If this answer isn't what you look for, could you be a bit more specific about the method please ?

Comment: We aren't using linear dependence. We are asked to proof with just simple matrix, knowledge.

Comment: Ok, well linear dependence is one of the first things I learned about matrices, but you could also try and solve the system $Ax=0$
and end up with (sorry for the spoil) infinitely many solutions, or you could just point out one non-trivial solution... Would this be better ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that looking at the $(3,3)$-entry alone is insufficient to prove that $A$ is singular. It is "natural" to think that a single equation in four unknowns $(x,y,z,t) x_3 = e_3$ is "very likely" to have solution, in contrast to your conclusion of the equation having no solution.

("Usually" when there are more unknowns than equations, there will be infinitely many solutions. On the contrary if there are more equations than unknowns, there will "usually" be no solutions. Of course, one main objective of studying linear algebra is to make a precise justification for determining the number of solutions.)

There are some simple proofs if you have learnt the equivalence relations about whether a matrix is singular.

---

If you have learnt about determinant and its theory, then the proof is as simple as:

$$\det(A) = \prod_{i=1}^4 A_{ii} = 0,$$
where the first equality is due to the triangular structure of $A$. This shows $A$ is singular.

---

Alternatively, you can show that the homogenous equation $Ax=0$ has a nontrivial solution, for example, $x = (-2,-8,3,0)^T$.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what does your teacher means by a proof by row.

One possibility is that perhaps compute the RREF and if you see a zero row in the RREF, the matrix is not invertible.